# Do not auto-capitalize when editing an equation in AUCTeX or org-mode

Tags: org-mode, auctex, capitalization

I would like the [`auto-capitalize`](http://melpa.org/#/auto-capitalize) minor mode not to capitalize mathematical text in AUCTeX and org-mode.

To avoid this, when running in either of these modes, auto-capitalize should only capitalize when the function `texmathp` returns `nil`.

The auto-capitalize code is quite messy, so I don't know what is the best place to make this modification so that everything keeps running efficiently.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Auto-capitalize defines the variable `auto-capitalize-predicate`, which can be used to check whether to enable auto-capitalization based on context.

Try this

```
(setq auto-capitalize-predicate (lambda () (not (texmathp))))
```

to turn it off in LaTeX formulas.